# Laravel Collection group by hour

Tags: laravel, collections

I have collection from MongoDB:

```
$collection = DB::connection('test')
        ->collection('test')->get();
```

Collection example:

```
{ a: b, c: d, created_at: "2021-01-01 10:10:10" }
{ a: b, c: d, created_at: "2021-01-01 11:10:10" }
```

Is it possible to group collection by hour? 10..11..12 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it works

```
$array = [
           ['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd', 'created_at' => '2021-01-01 10:10:10'],
           ['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd', 'created_at' => '2021-01-01 11:10:10'],
         ];
$collect = collect($array);
$collect = $collect->groupBy(function($collect){
     return date('H',strtotime($collect['created_at']));
});
dd($collect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
 $array = [
            ['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd', 'created_at' => '2021-01-01 10:10:10'],
            ['a' => 'b', 'c' => 'd', 'created_at' => '2021-01-01 11:10:10'],
        ];
        collect($array)->groupBy(function ($data)
        {
            return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $data['created_at'])->hour;
        })->dd();
```

Result:

[image]